# Combine two different textures so that one appears in the shadows as Earth rotates?

Tags: texturing, uv

I just watched to this amazing example on how to animate Earth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yz_-U7t8AU

So I ask: **is it possible to combine the two different textures below so that the night Earth (with lights on) appears in the shaddow region as Earth rotates?**

[image]

Sources of images:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans_12000.jpg
- https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/new-night-lights-maps-open-up-possible-real-time-applications/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping two image texture on a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45274/mapping-two-image-texture-on-a-sphere) and [how to make texture appear only in dark spots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116394/how-to-make-texture-appear-only-in-dark-spots) and [how to mix two materials based on incoming light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/how-can-i-mix-two-materials-based-on-incoming-light)

Comment: Yes. Sure. It is a duplicate. The second link is similar to my question. And the answer seems to solve my problem. I will try now. Thank you. I probably didn't search with appropriate terms to find the posts you suggested. Thank you again!